# Format for including @api recordId in JSON.parse

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json, lightning-record-page

I have a Lightning record page and just want to include the `recordId` in my JSON string variables passed to Flow. I understand including the decorator, etc I just cannot seem to get the correct format for including the `recordId` in the `JSON.parse(this.flowParams)`. Passing regular String variables are working fine.

I'm also not clear if using this pattern I still need to include the `recordId`in the `<targetConfig><property>` section? I think no.

```
[{"name": "recordId", "type": "String", "value": "{!recordId}"}]
```

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class cardNpiSingFlowCmp extends LightningElement {
  @api flowName;
  @api recordId;
  @api flowParams;
  @api vaEntryPoint;

    get inputVariables() {
          return JSON.parse(this.flowParams);
    }
    
    handleStatusChange(event) {
        if (event.detail.status === 'FINISHED') {
            // set behavior after a finished flow interview
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just spread it into a new object and add the `recordId` property.

```
return { ...JSON.parse(this.flowParams), recordId };
```

Comment: Somethings not quite right with the syntax at least because `return {JSON.parse(this.flowParams), recordId};` is giving me compiler errors. `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: That's not what I have in my post though. The `...` is a very important piece of the syntax. See [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Missed that piece thought just ellipses. Still not working but now wondering if because I'm trying to pass the recordId to an autolaunched Flow? Doesn't seem like I should be having so much trouble with this part. When I include `recordId` as another property I'm either not using correct syntax to pass `{!recordId}`, which is not accepted in LEX page, or I don't see it if leaving assignment out as docs suggest its passed automatically if on LEX Record page which it is.